# How to change the user name in the computer

Tags: android-studio, anaconda, rename

My computer name is "CharanKumar". When ever i try to install any software (Anaconda, Android Studio) it says that the space character will create problems.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't that your user name and not your computer name?

Comment: @JamesZ "CHARAN KUMAR" is the user name, "Charankumar" is the computer name. Kindly look the attachments in the question

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with space character in destination folder. In ur case it should be C:\Users\CharanKumar\Anaconda3 instead of C:\Users\Charan Kumar\Anaconda3. 
Try this C:\Users\CharanKumar\Anaconda3 u won't see this warning.